# Transformation of Operation Order for H,T Single Quantum Gate

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

Suppose I want to apply an $H$-gate transformation to an arbitrary quantum state $|\sigma\rangle$, and then a $T$-gate transformation to the arbitrary quantum state $|\sigma\rangle$.

The quantum state is transformed into $TH|\sigma\rangle$.

But I can't do $H$-gate first now, I only can use a $T$-gate first.  The quantum state transformation is $T|\sigma\rangle$, regardless of the global phase.

How do I transform to get the quantum state $TH|\sigma\rangle$ which is what I want at the beginning?

To explain my question, an example is given below:

$$R_x(\theta)^aR_z(\theta)^b=(-1)^{ab}R_z(\theta)R_x(\theta).$$

Comment: Can you please restate more clearly? Please, fix the punctuation and ask a clear question.

Comment: What gates are you allowed to do? For example, are you allowed to apply $THT^\dagger$ to your state $T|\sigma\rangle$?

Comment: Sorry, I revised my question and hope it can be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ denote the desired unitary, i.e. $U$ is such that $UT|\sigma\rangle = TH|\sigma\rangle$ for any $|\sigma\rangle$. If two operators yield the same result on every input, then they are equal. Therefore, $UT=TH$. Finally, hit both sides with $T^\dagger$ from the right to find $U=THT^\dagger$.